# jQuery Nav's anchor click not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, nav

I have a Home.html screen and its corresponding Angularjs controller(HomeController.js). I am using  [jQuery Navigation sidebar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Off-canvas-Sidebar-Navigation-Plugin-with-jQuery/) on home screen. This navigation sidebar has a logout list item (li). I have given ng-click="logout()" to this li (list item), and I have defined logout() in HomeController.js.

When I click on logout, It doesn't give alert, probably it's not going to this controller.

**Home.html**

```
<nav id="menu">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sidebar-nav-menu">
        <div class="menu_nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="logout();">
                        <img  src="img/left-pannel/logout@2x.png" id="nav-icn-home" alt="" class="sidebar-menu-icons">
                        <span class="nav-menu-text">Logout</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></nav>
```

**HomeController.js**

```
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $location, $window, $compile) {
$scope.logout = function(){
    alert("Click");
    $location.path("/Login");
}});
```

**config.js**

```
var tkitApp = angular.module('tkit', ['ngRoute']);tkitApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {       
    templateUrl: 'views/LaunchScreen.html',
    controller: 'LaunchScreenController'
}).when('/Login', {        
    templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
    controller: 'LoginScreenController'
}).when('/Home', {        
    templateUrl: 'views/Home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
 }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });}]);
```

I am not even getting alert on click of **logout** list item.

Logcat when Home.html gets loaded

```
03-11 17:34:37.530: I/chromium(29156): [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "HomeController loaded", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/controller/HomeScreenController.js (2)
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What if you remove the ; in your ng-click= call to logout()?
If still has a problem I'd suggest removing a lot of code and keeping it very simple, and getting that to work first.

Comment: Thanks @VictorySaber, there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 3):

Your controller name is different in routing

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {       
    templateUrl: 'views/LaunchScreen.html',
    controller: 'LaunchScreenController'
}).when('/Login', {        
    templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
    controller: 'LoginScreenController'
}).when('/Home', {        
    templateUrl: 'views/Home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
 }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });}]);
```

And Controller is

```
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $location, $window, $compile) {
$scope.logout = function(){
    alert("Click");
    $location.path("/Login");
}});
```

Please change your controller name like this

```
app.controller("HomeScreenController", function ($scope, $location, $window, $compile) {
    $scope.logout = function(){
        alert("Click");
        $location.path("/Login");
    }});
```

It will work

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Please check my updated question. Sorry, In my code, Both places have same controller name, made mistake while copying to notepad (I was trying to change controller name.) and notepad to Stackoverflow. It's not the problem. I did double check.

Comment: Can you please console.log in controller so we can ensure that your controller is load